# getting style error for display with JS but works smoothly in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, typeerror, jsfiddle

I have the code below. My desired outcome is exactly how it is in jsfiddle: works perfectly! In my browser, I get these two errors that differentiate it:

code:

http://jsfiddle.net/pbvwjL94/1/

```
GET http://localhost/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

realjs.js:236 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at showForm (realjs.js:236)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (testwriting.php:57)
```

In my browser, the writing sections work perfectly and the reading section works when I choose science. However, the error still appears. The other sections just do not work.

I know it is a lot of code but I have been scouring the web for answers for so long and nobody has been able to help me.

I really need it guys

Thanks

As asked, here is my element with id f9

```
<div class="form-group" name="skill5" id="f9" style="display:none">
      <select class="form-control" name="skill5" id="readingsocialstudies" onchange="showForm()" data-required>
        <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-Select Your Skill-</option>
        <option value="Big Picture">Big Picture</option>
        <option value="Attention to Detail">Attention to Detail</option>
        <option value="Inference">Making Inferences</option>
        <option value="Function">Identifying Function</option>
        <option value="Vocabulary In Context">Vocabulary In Context</option>
        <option value="Analogy">Drawing Analogies</option>
        <option value="Author Technique">Author Technique</option>
        <option value="Evidence Support">Supporting with Evidence</option>
        <option value="Data Reasoning">Data Reasoning</option>
      </select>   
      <br style="line-height:10px;">
      <select class="form-control" name="passageid1" data-required>
        <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-Select Your Passage ID-</option>
          <?php 
            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ID FROM excerptlist");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
              $ID = $row['ID'];
              echo "<option value='".$ID."'>" . $ID . "</option>";
            }
          ?>
      </select>  
    </div>
```

Comment: So it can not find the element you are selecting

Comment: @epascarello do you mind editing my code? my code works in jsfiddle so there should be no problem

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @JuanCaicedo thank you!!! check out my response to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The error message points you to line 236

```
document.getElementById("f9").style.display = "none";
```

Looking at your html, there's no element with id `f9`. This means that `document.getElementById("f9")` will return `null`, and it's not possible to get the property `.style` on that.

If you add the correct element, I think your code will work fine

Comment: Hey Juan, thank you so so much for the response. I do have already have an element with id f9. check my edit.

Comment: @robert Are you seeing a different error now? Given that everything works fine in your jsfiddle, it's hard to know how else to help 

Comment: no. do you mind running it locally and seeing if you get the same problem

Comment: If you are want to set up a git repo that demonstrates the problem so that it's easy to get up and running, I'm glad to help  Otherwise, it's a lot to ask for someone to set up a whole codebase without knowing exactly what set up they're trying to produce 